# Observable issue with angular / ionic template

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I've got an observable returning data from Firestore using the AFS module. Everything seems fine, but I can't get anything to reach the template.

**list.ts**

```
...
  list$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor() {
     this.listDocumentRef = *REDACTED*;
     this.list$ = this.listDocumentRef.snapshotChanges().map(action => { 
        return action.payload.data();
     }); 
    this.list$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
...
```

**list.html**

```
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of list$.items | async" >
      <ion-label>{{item.item}}</ion-label> 
    </ion-item>
```

So, the **console** is returning:

```
{items: Array(2)}
items:
Array(2)
0:{item: "cheese"}
1:{item: "butter"}
```

Which suggests I'm really close, but struggling to see what step I'm missing!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your case but something like this should work:

**list.ts**

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';


public list$: Observable<Array<any>>;

ngOnInit() {

  this.<something iterable to subscribe to>.subscribe((response) => {
    this.list$ = Observable.of(response)
  });
}
```